# Is closure of Borel set Borel?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra of the reals $\mathbb{R}$
and $\bar{B}$ be the closure of a set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$.
Does $B \in \mathcal{B} \Rightarrow \bar{B}\in\mathcal{B}$ hold?

If yes, is there a quick proof (a reference to a book would be sufficient).
If no, counterexample?

Thx for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, the closure of any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed set, hence a Borel set, so the implication is true.